# how to solve an error when running generate-vapid-keys --json web-push?

Tags: powershell, terminal, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

Why when running web-push generate-vapid-keys --json there is an error:

> web-push: The term 'web-push' is not recognized as the name of a
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
> of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
> correct and try again. At line: 1 char: 1
>
> - web-push generate-vapid-keys --json
> - ```
>      + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (web-push: String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException
>   ```

What's the solution?

[Push-Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ4n3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

web-push isn't part of Powershell instead its an [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push).  If you have nodejs installed try running the command below first:

```
npm install web-push -g
```